# how to get all the child id in an ExpandableListView without depending on the parent group

Tags: java, android

I've designed a GUI with an `ExpandableListView`, please see sample picture below.

[image: Screenshot of the GUI]

I want to know if it is possible to get the `IDs` of all the child in the list without having to depend on the parent group.

Presently what I'm able to get is 0-2 for the first Parent and the second parent also starts from 0.

So basically I want to get the IDs like:

- Fixture ?  id(0)
- Chillers ?  id(1)
- Displays ?  id(2)
- "33" Export (Can) id(3)
  etc.

Here my `Custom adapter` class:

```
public class MTOExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

  private Context _context;
  private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
  // child data in format of header title, child title
  private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

  public MTOExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
  }

  @Override
  public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getGroupId(int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mto_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mto_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMTOListItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom adapter like a `BaseExpandableListAdapter` subclass? If you are, could you post that code?  Usually when I have a requirement like this, I just add a non-override method to my adapter e.g. `getAllChildIds` and use that.

Comment: @krislarson Please see the class with the custom adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I see what you are asking.  You are trying to get a unique ID for every child of every group, in numerical order.

```
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        int id = 0;
        for (int group = 0; group < groupPosition; group++) {
            id += getChildrenCount(group);
        }
        id += childPosition;
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: hi, Kris larson, I've attempted your answer, however something seem to be wrong. If you look at the screenshot I posted alongside my question, when I clicked on the first 3 child, I got the right value which are 0,1 and 2. But when I clicked on " "33" Export (Can) " which should give me id 3 instead the id jumps to 7.
NB: I removed group from the method getGroupCount() as the method does not require parameter.

Comment: I will also like to ask if you could assist with setting background color for each of the child after clicking it. I have done it by calling the method getChildView() but when I click the any of the first 3 child, it set the background but also set for other child that I haven't click.

Comment: You have overridden `isChildSelectable` to return `true`, so I think it works like this: In your child layout XML, set a background that is a `StateListDrawable` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList .  The item with `android:state_selected="true"` should show when user selects a child.  Try it out, and if you need more help, post another SO question and leave a link to that question in a comment here so I see it.